# Coldfusion timestamp datatype error

Tags: coldfusion, stripe-payments

I am implementing an external wrapper for the Stripe API in Coldfusion.

One of the functions I am calling takes an argument of type "timestamp", as seen below:

```
public struct function updateSubscription(required string customerid, required string planid, string coupon='', boolean prorate=true, timestamp trial_end, any card) 
{
...
}
```

I am passing a valid date (tested and IsDate() resulted in "YES") to the trial_end argument but it is giving me a "not of type timestamp" error.

What do I need to do to this date to get the function call to work properly?

Thanks

UPDATE: FULL FUNCTION ADDED:

```
public struct function updateSubscription(required string customerid, required string planid, string coupon='', boolean prorate=true, timestamp trial_end, any card) {

    local.HTTPService = createHTTPService('POST');
    local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='plan',value=arguments.planid);

    local.HTTPService.setUrl(getBaseUrl() & 'customers/' & arguments.customerid & '/subscription');
    if (Len(Trim(arguments.coupon))) {
        local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='coupon',value=Trim(arguments.coupon));
    }
    local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='prorate',value=arguments.prorate);
    if (StructKeyExists(arguments,'trial_end') AND IsDate(arguments.trial_end)) {
        loca.intUTCDate = timeToUTCInt(arguments.trial_end);
        local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='trial_end',value=local.intUTCDate);
    }
    if (StructKeyExists(arguments,'card') AND isStruct(arguments.card)) {
        local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='card[number]',value=arguments.card.number);
        local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='card[exp_month]',value=arguments.card.exp_month);
        local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='card[exp_year]',value=arguments.card.exp_year);
        if (StructKeyExists(arguments,'card.cvc')) {
            local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='card[cvc]',value=arguments.card.cvc);
        }
        if (StructKeyExists(arguments,'card.name') AND Len(Trim(arguments.card.name))) {
            local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='card[name]',value=arguments.card.name);
        }
        if (StructKeyExists(arguments,'card.address_line1') AND Len(Trim(arguments.card.address_line1))) {
            local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='card[address_line1]',value=Trim(arguments.card.address_line1));
        }
        if (StructKeyExists(arguments,'card.address_line2') AND Len(Trim(arguments.card.address_line2))) {
            local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='card[address_line2]',value=Trim(arguments.card.address_line2));
        }
        if (StructKeyExists(arguments,'card.address_zip') AND Len(Trim(arguments.card.address_zip))) {
            local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='card[address_zip]',value=Trim(arguments.card.address_zip));
        }
        if (StructKeyExists(arguments,'card.address_state') AND Len(Trim(arguments.card.address_state))) {
            local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='card[address_state]',value=Trim(arguments.card.address_state));
        }
        if (StructKeyExists(arguments,'card.address_country') AND Len(Trim(arguments.card.address_country))) {
            local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='card[address_country]',value=Trim(arguments.card.address_country));
        }
    } else if (StructKeyExists(arguments,'card')) {
        local.HTTPService.addParam(type='formfield',name='card',value=Trim(arguments.card));
    }
    local.HTTPResult = local.HTTPService.send().getPrefix();

    if (NOT isDefined("local.HTTPResult.statusCode")) {
        throw(type='Stripe',errorcode="stripe_unresponsive", message="The Stripe server did not respond.", detail="The Stripe server did not respond.");
    } else if (left(local.HTTPResult.statusCode,3) NEQ "200") {
        throw(type='Stripe',errorcode=local.HTTPResult.statusCode, message=local.HTTPResult.statuscode, detail=local.HTTPResult.filecontent);
    }
    return deserializeJSON(local.HTTPResult.filecontent);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`timestamp` is not a native [CF data type](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e47.html), so CF is trying to find a CFC called timestamp.cfc.

I think you just mean `date` in this case.

Comment: Based on the googling I did I would agree. Do oyu think it is a bug in this person's implementation of the Stripe.cfc then? This is a CFC recommended by the people at Stripe which makes me want to question making any changes myself.

Comment: I would say that's definitely a mistake. It's possible that the script was tested on a system that wasn't checking argument types (an option in the CF Administrator). The only way that type would work was if it was passed another object that was of type timestamp (timestamp.cfc). I'd have to see the rest of the function to know if they're expecting a simple value or a complex object.

Comment: @Dan Short: I have added the full function. As you can see, it expects a simple string / date object.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely wrong.  You should advise the "vendor" of Stripe.cfc: they'll want to know.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that it does work when the datatype is changed to Date. Also, if you look at the function above you will see other obvious errors such as "loca." instead of "local.". Not very reassuring for an "approved" library.